# React doesn't update child when props change?

Tags: reactjs

Given the code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dervied-state-from-props-problem-2r0js

If you click on 'Ok' or 'Cancel' to close the editor after editing an item and then opening another item, this seems to be working fine. But try clicking on the edit button for any other item without closing the editor: the values in the editor remain the same even though the props have changed.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please include code in your question instead of using separate link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't update state in StatefulEditor when props change. You need to add `useEffect` to update.

```
const StatefulEditor = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(props.item.name);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(props.item.description);

  useEffect(() => {
    setName(props.item.name);
    setDescription(props.item.description);
  }, [props.item]);

...
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dervied-state-from-props-problem-forked-uiidu?file=/src/components/EditableList.jsx

Comment: Right, but why is that the case? Why is the component state not using the new props?

Comment: Because you don't update state in StatefulEditor when props change.